# Intermittent iFrame Height

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe, facebook-java-sdk

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
     FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 6000 }); 
} 
window.fbAsyncInit();   
</script>
```

This resizes my iFrame correctly about 50% of the time. The other 50% of the time it does not resize and the following error appears on my console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined
window.fbAsyncInit:122
(anonymous function)
```

At first I thought this was an error with how I embedded the Facebook Javascript SDK, but then why does it work sometimes and not at other times?

Comment: See here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556941/facebook-javascript-sdk-problem-fb-is-not-defined

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried the suggestions on there to no avail. My problem is not exclusive to Chrome either, same behaviour in IE and FF...

Comment: What about the code suggested in my answer? Have you tried it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be "race condition" of some sort, so just wait until FB is defined:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function FbAsynchInit() { 
     if (typeof FB != "undefined" && FB) {
         FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 6000 }); 
     } else {
         window.setTimeout(FbAsynchInit, 10);
     }
}
```

When FB won't be defined it will keep checking every 10 milliseconds, until it's defined.

Comment: @tomis Facebook count on their script to be loaded fast enough, probably sometimes that's not the case and it's loaded only after the main script trying to call it.

Comment: Understand that... Just wondering why facebook does not care about if fallback...