# listener like and unlike button out from iframe application

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

I make an iframe application for a fan page, the problem is that if user click on LIKE in top bar of facebook it reload application iframe page but dont refresh if user click on UNLIKE in same position

My applicatioon check if user is LIKE o NOT LIKE to the fan page and it cannot proceed if first dont click on LIKE button (the like button intend the button in top bar that out of iframe application)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '<?php echo $app_id; ?>', // App ID
  status     : true, // check login status
  channelUrl : '//www. domain .it/<?php echo $sub_dir_app; ?>/cf.php', // Channel File
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response) {
//top.location.reload();
    alert('ok NOLIKE');
});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
//top.location.reload();
    alert('ok LIKE');
});
};
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

Comment: for example you can see this application: https://www.facebook.com/extremesilver.gioielli/app_119909504798072 , first click on LIKE and you can see refresh, pasr you click on UNLIKE and see the refresh of iframe application, in standard application the refresh for UNLIKE dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Javascript SDK with the method `'FB.Event.subscribe'`. The events are:
`edge.create` - Like
`edge.remove` - Unlike

Read more:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: I initialize FB. but when I put FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response) {
 alert('ok NOLIKE');
}); but I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined

Comment: you need to define FB as described here under the 'Loading' section:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: I defined FB in my application iframe

Comment: Please edit your original answer with the code snippets you posted here. I find it difficult to understand it in the comments section. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have <div id="fb-root"></div> defined in the HTML?

Comment: Does it work in Firefox?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556941/facebook-javascript-sdk-problem-fb-is-not-defined

Comment: but FB.Event.subscribe must be in or out of window.fbAsyncInit = function() {... }

Comment: inside the scope of window.fbAsyncInit

Comment: Firefox response is: FB is not defined