# Angular --prod mode does not inject facebook service

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, angular-services

I am using `angular 7` and `ngx-facebook` service to login with facebook. This is the main component I am injecting `FacebookService` service.

app.module.ts

```js
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {FacebookModule} from 'ngx-facebook';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {UsercardDirective} from './usercard.directive';
import {UsercardComponent} from './usercard/usercard.component';
import {BodyComponent} from './body/body.component';
import {BoardComponent} from './board/board.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import { LandingComponent } from './landing/landing.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UsercardDirective,
    UsercardComponent,
    BodyComponent,
    BoardComponent,
    LandingComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FacebookModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

AppComponent.ts

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FacebookService} from 'ngx-facebook';
import {IndexserviceService} from './indexservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [IndexserviceService, FacebookService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'indexng';

  constructor(private inSrvc: IndexserviceService, private fb: FacebookService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.fb);
    this.inSrvc.indexInit(this.fb);
  }
}
```

I get some strange results. When I am testing this with **`ng-serve` it works fine.**

**Then I ran `ng g --prod` and put the app in spring boot app. there I get the console output of `this.fb` as an empty object.**

***both the time `IndexserviceService` is working fine. `indexInit` gets called properly**

Comment: have you imported the module in your AppModule?, you can also remove the providers line in the @Component decorator

Comment: @DamienLegros no. I have updated the question. and should I add the service in that provider array?

Comment: No, you don't have to add the FacebookService in any providers arrays

Comment: @DamienLegros so above code is enough?

Comment: I suspect `this.fb` hasn't been initialized yet at point of execution. Because it is likely an async method that is calling facebook sdk (the `<script>` tag you had added to index.html). ngOnInit() is only executed once on app component initialization. I have never used this package before, but I had faced a similar issue in the past when adding facebook sdk to an Angular project. Have a read on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556941/facebook-javascript-sdk-problem-fb-is-not-defined

Comment: Also, have a read at the installation instructions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-facebook#installation. You seem to be missing **step 4** of the instructions. You have to pass Facebook SDK your developer app ID, and so on before you will get a response (fb object).

Comment: @Riv thanks. when I try to do the 4th step I get the error. fb.init is not defined.

Comment: did you call `fb.init(initParams)` in the constructor as required? If you have made any changes, do remember to edit your question so other more knowledgeable people on facebook sdk can help you